# Can I trap SIGSEGV (on a Linux) and what are are the conditions to make it works? (for a crackme)

Tags: linux, crackme

I'm writing some crackmes.one challenge and I want to write a challenge where the solution appears on a segmentation fault. (And you have to disassemble the code to find a way to segfault. It should be fun, right?)

I found some hard-to-understand theoretical answer here and there but I can't find a practical solution. Because most of the question are "how to recover from a sigsegv" and most of the answer are "you can't, make your code right so it doesn't segfault".

What would be the most "trap-able" segfault? a call to a null function pointer? a double-free? ...?

What can I do in my signal handler? It seems there are some harsh condition (reentrancy, async-signal-safe function, etc...).

If someone can give me some safe pointer (pun intended) to some kind of documentation, blog, ... or an explanation a bit more useful than "just read the POSIX bible". It would be greatly appreciated.

My code doesn't need to be portable. If it works on a moderately standard Linux (Debian, Redhat, Ubuntu, CentOS) it will be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution working in Windows was given in [my question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21367/debug-program-using-peculiar-anti-debugging-technique) - this way, you can cause program to continue after it receives `SIGSEGV`.

You can do similar thing on linux (though I would recommend using `sigaction` instead of `signal` which is deprecated (see [link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html))). That is, register signal handler for this signal and cause it whichever way you prefer to - execution will be passed to the handler, where you can continue.

An example code is given below:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void handler(int sig)
{
    write(1, "success", strlen("success")); // printf is not recommended here, but should work as well
    exit(0);
}

int main()
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    memset (&sa, '\0', sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_sigaction = &handler;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL); // register handler for SIGSEGV
    int *a; // a will contain some garbage value
    int b = *a; // trigger segmentation fault; transfer control to handler
}
```

Of course, you can use the same trick as in my example on Windows and continue the execution outside `handler`.

Comment: Thank you ! i bookmarked the post you linked and will read it too. I don't have enough reputation to upvote you but your answer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can accept it if you feel it answered your question. And if not, let me know about any doubts, so I can improve it.

Answer (score 2):

An excellent reference (probably the best one) that can be consulted for this type of problem is [The Linux Programming Interface](http://man7.org/tlpi/), which includes 3 full chapters on the topic of signals:

- Signals: Fundamental Concepts
- Signals: Signal Handlers
- Signals: Advanced features

These chapters include example code as well as diagrams and clear explanations.
(A free pdf of the book can easily be found online.)

See also: [Binary Obfuscation Using Signals](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/~debray/Publications/obf-signal.pdf)

To your questions:

> What would be the most "trap-able" segfault ? a call to a null function pointer ? a double-free ? ... ?

A signal handler, should it exist, will be called by the kernel on the basis of the signal (specifically, its number as defined in `<signal.h>`), rather than the specific event that triggered the signal. This means that you are free to decide what kind of invalid memory reference to make in order to trigger a segmentation fault. Dereferencing a null pointer is probably the most reliable, since it guarantees program behavior will be deterministic, as a segmentation fault will always occur irrespective of stack contents or the layout of the process in memory.

---

> What can i do in my signal handler ? It seems there are some harsh condition (reentrancy, async-signal-safe function,...).

You have several options. But first, a bit about non-reentrant library functions:

> Functions can also be *nonreentrant* if they use static data structures for their
>   internal bookkeeping. The most obvious examples of such functions are the members of the `stdio` library (`printf()`, `scanf()`, and so on), which update internal data structures for buffered I/O. Thus, when using `printf()` from within a signal handler, we may sometimes see strange output—or even a program crash or data corruption—if the handler interrupts the main program in the middle of executing a call to `printf()` or another `stdio` function.

The important part is the last sentence. Implementing an exception handler for `SIGSEGV` may result in unintended signal handler behavior if non-reentrant library functions are called within the exception handler, since it may be possible to trigger a segmentation fault outside of the specific conditions you anticipate. For example, when user input is read into a buffer via `scanf`, unless bounds checking is properly implemented, a buffer overflow due to 1000 'A's being entered can result in `SIGSEGV` being sent to the process, which will then trigger the exception handler during the execution of an `stdio` function. If the signal handler also calls an `stdio` function, undefined behavior may occur.

- The most interesting approach for your case would probably be changing the `uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP]` (RIP here is the x86-64 instruction pointer) value in the signal handler's `context` struct to point to a function somewhere else in the program. After the signal handler finishes, program execution would resume at that function. Alternatively, the `uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP]` value can incremented to skip/jump over the instructions that caused the signal handler to execute in the first place. This means that the signal handler could be designed to simply jump to a different location in the program upon  receiving `SIGSEGV`. This approach, (or alternatively, executing a nonlocal goto), eliminates the need for any I/O to be performed by the signal handler (no need for `printf()`, etc.). The drawback is that this approach is architecture-dependent. Examples illustrating this technique can be found in the following article: [Linux - Writing Fault Handlers](https://devarea.com/linux-writing-fault-handlers/#.XRsCCnXwbVO). Some related example code can also be found here: [In a signal handler, how to know where the program is interrupted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768426/in-a-signal-handler-how-to-know-where-the-program-is-interrupted)
- Note that since it is possible for a process to send a signal to itself, it is not necessary to choose `SIGSEGV` as the handled signal; `getpid()` and `kill()` can be used to send some other signal to the process in order to trigger the signal handler.
- Additionally, it is possible to execute a non-local goto from within the exception handler itself via functions `sigsetjmp()` and `siglongjmp()`. Unlike using `uc_mcontext.gregs[XXX]` to modify the instruction pointer, this approach appears to be portable:

  - > In general, it is preferable to write simple signal handlers. One important reason for this is to reduce the risk of creating race conditions. Two common designs for signal handlers are the following:
    >
    > - The signal handler sets a global flag and exits. The main program periodically
    >     checks this flag and, if it is set, takes appropriate action. (If the main program
    >     cannot perform such periodic checks because it needs to monitor one or more
    >     file descriptors to see if I/O is possible, then the signal handler can also write a single byte to a dedicated pipe whose read end is included among the file
    >     descriptors monitored by the main program. We show an example of this technique in Section 63.5.2.)
    > - The signal handler performs some type of cleanup and then either terminates
    >     the process or uses a nonlocal goto (Section 21.2.1) to unwind the stack and
    >     return control to a predetermined location in the main program.
  - > [Executing a nonlocal goto] provides a way to recover after delivery of a signal caused by a hardware exception (e.g., a memory access error), and also allows us to catch a signal and return control to a particular point in a program. For example, upon receipt of a SIGINT signal (normally generated by typing Control-C), the shell performs a nonlocal goto to return control to its main input loop (and thus read a new command).

---

Supplementary info:

[image: Signal delivery and handler execution]

> A signal is a notification to a process that an event has occurred. Signals are sometimes described as software interrupts. Signals are analogous to hardware interrupts in that they interrupt the normal flow of execution of a program; in most cases, it is not possible to predict exactly when a signal will arrive.
>   One process can (if it has suitable permissions) send a signal to another process.
>   In this use, signals can be employed as a synchronization technique, or even as a
>   primitive form of interprocess communication (IPC). It is also possible for a process to send a signal to itself. However, the usual source of many signals sent to a process is the kernel.

---

Reference: The Linux Programming Interface, chapters 20 and 21

Comment: Thank you <3 I just finished my latest crackme (guild hall adventure) and will implement this trick in chapter 4 ! :)

Comment: @ker2x you’re welcome and I look forward to trying to solve your new crackme programs :)